# Selenium / Python 3 - send_keys() performing slowly Safari

Tags: python, selenium, safari, sendkeys

I have the following code:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').send_keys(x)
```

I am using Safari as my browser and when it runs it is very slow at typing in the characters instead of a fast copy/paste that you can do manually (and I expected). The length of string "x" is typically ~400 but can be as high as 2000. Is there a better way to send long strings or do I just have to live with it?

Comment: did you try with newer safaridriver, if still not resolve your issue,  set text by javascript may be an option:  driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', inputElement, stringToTypeInto)

Comment: I will check on both of these items and let you know. Thanks